# SQL(Left Join) Get all recipes which have all their ingredients in another table

Tags: mysql, sql, database, sqlite

I need to get all recipes where all the ingredients are in another table and I don't know how I could to this.

> 'Ingredients' table (from the recipes):

1. Column is an ingredient id (unique)
2. Column is the recipe id for each ingredient
3. Column is the ingredient (at the moment string)

> 'UserIngredients' table (from the user):

1. Column is again just an id (unique)
2. Column is the ingredient

## An example:

Ingredients table (of the recipes): [image: The Ingredients table]
User ingredients table:

[image]

Now I just want to get recipe id 13 back because this recipe just needs 'Butter' and 'Mehl'. What I don't want to get are the recipes which also need 'Butter' and 'Mehl' but also something else, because that's not in the user ingredients table.

**Now I want a query(I think with an Inner Join) to get the recipes(ids) which have all ingredients in the other table.** I hope you understand my problem and can help me. Big Thank You!

Comment: It would be easier to present the requirement with sample data of both tables and the expected results.

Comment: I added the example

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need a `LEFT` join of `ingredients` to `useringredients` and then `group by recipeid`:

```
select i.recipeid
from ingredients i left join useringredients ui
on ui.ingredient = i.ingredient
group by i.recipeid
having count(*) = count(ui.ingredient)
```

The condition `having count(*) = count(ui.ingredient)` makes sure that all ingredients and no more are used for that `recipeid`